# Maximal homogeneous ideals in graded ring A[T]

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, graded-rings

Let $A$ be a commutative algebra with unit. Let $A[x]$ be the polynomial algebra with coefficients in $A$ with the standard gradation (by degrees).

I have the following questions.

What are maximal homogeneous ideal in $A[x]$ not containing $A[x]_{+}:=\bigoplus\limits_{n>0}Ax^n$? How can I describe them in terms of maximal ideals in $A$?

My idea is something like:

If $I \subset A$ maximal ideal, then $\bigoplus\limits_{n\geq0}Ix^n$ is a maximal ideal among them that not contain $A[x]_+$. But it looks like miss something.

Comment: $(x^2,\mathfrak{m})$. The ideal generated by $x^2$ and the $a_i$ where $a_i$ are the generators of some maximal ideal of $A$.

Comment: Ok, basically is maximal at degree 1 and $Ax^n$ for $n>1$, right? Are you saying that they have all this form?

Comment: why the tag "geometry" ?

Comment: Because we can say this inside scheme theory. Maximal homogeneous ideals not containing the irrelevant ideal $A[x]_+$ are the geometric point of the scheme $Proj(A[x])$. Maximal ideals of $A$ are the geometric point of the scheme $Spec A$. For example, If $A=\mathbb{C}$, we recover $\mathbb{CP}^0$ "as Proj" and a point "as Spec".